# Python unusual file sorting

Tags: python, file, sorting

I have a txt file that contains data in the following fashion:

```
23       1      65      15      19.2
19       2      66      25      25.7
10       3      67      35      16.5
100      4      68      45      10.4
20       5      69      55      6.8
201      6      64      65      9.2
```

Within the file, each value is separated from other using \t and then \n for next line.

I want to sort this file based on the first values of the each line.
My expected output is :

```
10       3      67      35      16.5
19       2      66      25      25.7
20       5      69      55      6.8
23       1      65      15      19.2
100      4      68      45      10.4
201      6      64      65      9.2
```

But the actual output I am getting is as:

```
10       3      67      35      16.5
100      4      68      45      10.4
19       2      66      25      25.7
20       5      69      55      6.8
201      6      64      65      9.2
23       1      65      15      19.2
```

Its taking the values as strings and hence not taking the entire numbers value as integer.
I tried parsing, but its not working.

My code:

```
with open('filename.txt') as fin:
        lines = [line.split() for line in fin]
lines.sort(key=itemgetter(0),reverse=True)

with open('newfile.txt', 'w') as fout:
    for i in lines:
            fout.write('{0}\t\t\t\t\n'.format('\t\t\t '.join(i)))
```

Please help if possible.

Comment: Simply piping to `sort -n` will do the trick as well.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You're currently comparing strings, you need to compare integers:

```
lines.sort(key=lambda x:int(x[0]), reverse=True)
```

Strings are compared lexicographically, so:

```
>>> '2' > '100'
True
```

Conversion to `int` fixes this issue:

```
>>> int('2') > int('100')
False
```

Answer (score 2):

Also take a look at [pandas](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/10min.html), if you plane to make more complicated manipulations later, for example:

```
import pandas as pd

pd.read_table('filename.txt', header=None)\
            .sort(columns=0)\
            .to_csv('newfile.txt', sep='\t', header=None, index=False)
```

Comment: Hey I tried this but it needed pandas package to be installed..and I have n machines to deal with..so I dint opt for pandas. But thanks